# BMI Calculator in Bash Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to create a script using the Bash shell in Linux to calculate BMI.  I know that I am just doing something silly but I can't seem to make it work.  It wont do the division. Can you see where I've gone wrong

```
     #!/bin/bash
     #==============================================================
     # Script Name: bmicalc
     # By:          mhj
     # Date:        March 25, 2014
     # Purpose:     calculates your bmi from your weight & height
     #===============================================================
     #Get your weight and height
     echo -n "What is your weight in pounds? "
     read weight
     echo -n "What is your height in inches? "
     read height
     #calculate your bmi
     let total_weight=$weight*703
     let total_height=$height*$height
     bmi=$total_weight/$total_height
     echo "Your weight is $weight"
 echo "Your height is $height"
 echo -n "Your BMI is $bmi"
```

Comment: FYI, `let` is aniquated syntax; the modern form is `total_weight=$(( weight * 703 ))`, `total_height=$(( height * height ))`; etc.

Comment: ...that said, bash native math is integer-only; if you want an accurate number, you'll need floating-point math, which bash doesn't support. One common solution is to use awk for this.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022 for a detailed introduction to doing floating-point math from bash.

Comment: Nice project! :D I always admired bash programmers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need another `let`:

```
let bmi=$total_weight/$total_height
```

#### Alternatives

There are *so* many ways to have arithmetic context in the shell. The preferred, standard way is `$(( ))` syntax:

```
total_weight=$(( $weight * 703 ))
```

This and `expr` (see below) are pretty much the only ones that'll work in POSIX sh. (There's also `$[ ]`, but that's deprecated and mostly works the same as double-parens.)

You can gain some syntactical efficiency by declaring your variables as integers. Parameters with the *integer* attribute cause the RHS of all assignment expressions to have arithmetic context:

```
declare -i weight height bmi total_weight total_height
total_weight=weight*703
total_height=height*height
bmi=total_weight/total_height
```

No more `let`.

You can also use the `(( ))` syntax directly.

```
(( total_weight=weight*703 ))
(( total_height=height*height ))
(( bmi=total_weight/total_height ))
```

Finally, `expr` is just a pain in the shell.

```
total_weight=$(expr $weight '*' 703) # Have to escape the operator symbol or it will glob expand
total_height=$(expr $height '*' $height) # Also there's this crazy subshell
```

… meh, but completeness!

Finally, in bash arrays the index will always have arithmetic context. (But that doesn't really apply here.)

However, none of these approaches will do floating-point calculations, so your divisions will always be truncated. If you need fractional values, use `bc`, `awk`, or another programming language.

Comment: ...that said, the `declare -i` is a bashism, as is the use of `(( ))`, whereas `$(( ))` is POSIX compliant.

Comment: Ahh; I see this is clear now. (Did I miss that on my first read, or did you edit since?)

Comment: There: I think that's a survey of all the arithmetic expression context syntaxes.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma No, I mentioned it. See my recent edit.

Comment: I used declare -i weight height bmi total_weight total_height
total_weight=weight*703
total_height=height*height
bmi=total_weight/total_height and it worked.  I was looking for a general idea of the bmi and not a precise number so bash will work for me! Thanks

Comment: I never knew `declare -i`.  Thanks. `bash` has "types" after all ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you need a non-integer answer, you can use `bc`:

```
$ weight=160
$ height=70
$ echo "Your BMI is $(bc <<< "scale=3; ($weight * 703) / ($height * $height)")"
Your BMI is 22.955
$
```

`scale=3;` tells `bc` to output to 3 decimal places.  Change this according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with the variables? If you don't mind using native (integer-only) math, which is the same thing you're getting from `let`:

```
echo "Your BMI is $(( (weight * 703) / (height * height) ))"
```

...or, to use `awk` for a more accurate calculation:

```
awk -v weight="$weight" -v height="$height" \
  'BEGIN { printf "%f\n", ((weight * 703) / (height * height)) }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a pointer ... Bash doesn't do floating point math, only integer.  So your numbers for BMI are going to be off.  You should use `bc` to perform the math, if you're going to use division.

For example:

`7/3` = 2 (not 2.33333333)
`7%3` = 1

Answer (score 0):

I would use `bc` for this. The `scale` variable dictates the number of decimal places in the answer:

```
bmi=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $total_weight/$total_height")
```

Alternatively, you can use `-l` to load the standard math library, which sets `scale` to 20:

```
bmi=$(bc -l <<< "$total_weight/$total_height")
```

`awk` is always an option too:

```
bmi=$(awk -v w="$total_weight" -v h="$total_height" 'BEGIN { print w/h }')
```

Comment: *"If bc is invoked with the -l option, a math library is preloaded and the default scale is set to 20."*

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thanks, I looked in the manual but it just said "Define the standard math library.". Editing now